# блокируются запросы при открытии трех одинаковых вкладок

Tags: reactjs, axios

В приложении постоянно крутится таймер, который обновляет токены.
При открытии двух вкладок, все нормально.
При открытии третьей, запросы отваливаются по таймауту, причем все и во всех вкладках.
Смотрел в нгинксе, они туда даже попадают. т.е. что то с браузером или с axios. подозреваю какие то блокировки в браузере. Добавление хедеров отключающих кэширование не помогает. Сталкивался кто то с таким поведением ? Куда копать подскажите ?

```
async function retry<T>(todo: () => Promise<T>, retrys: number, delayMs: number): Promise<T> {
    let r = 0;
    let err;
    do {
        try {
            return await todo();
        } catch (error) {
            if (error.response?.data?.error === "invalid_grant") {
                throw error;
            }
            err = error;
            r = r + 1;
            //console.log(error);
            console.log(`Retry: ${r}`);
            if (r === retrys - 1) {
                throw error;
            }
            await sleep(delayMs);
        }
    } while (r < retrys)
    throw err;
}

export async function GetRefreshToken(username: string, password: string, pin: string) {
    let resp: AxiosResponse;
    const formData = new URLSearchParams();
    formData.append("username", username);
    formData.append("password", password);
    formData.append("grant_type", "password");
    formData.append("client_id", authClientId);
    formData.append("client_secret", authClientSecret);
    formData.append("scope", authScopes);
    formData.append("two_fa", pin);

    const client = axios.create();
    const options = {
        timeout: 5000,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        },
    };
    resp = await retry(async () => await client.post(tokenEndpoint, formData, options), 3, 5000);

    return resp.data;
}
```

пример запроса:

```
curl -iv 'https://fancrypto.ru/connect/token'   -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*'   -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache, no-transform, no-store, max-age=3, must-revalidate'   -H 'Referer: https://fancrypto.ru/invoices/invoice/14/1'   -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'   -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36'   -H 'Expires: -1'   --data-raw 'refresh_token=FA84B084C5D037A949167A60CB0BF5D418A146DB2923040C371D5DFD722E173B&grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=browser&client_secret=secret&scope=trade+profile_security+openid+offline_access'   --compressed
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to fancrypto.ru (127.0.0.1) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=www.fancrypto.ru
*  start date: Aug  9 12:19:30 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Aug 15 10:05:48 2021 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "fancrypto.ru" matched cert's "fancrypto.ru"
*  issuer: C=BE; O=GlobalSign nv-sa; CN=GlobalSign RSA DV SSL CA 2018
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> POST /connect/token HTTP/1.1
> Host: fancrypto.ru
> Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip, br
> Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
> Cache-Control: no-cache, no-transform, no-store, max-age=3, must-revalidate
> Referer: https://fancrypto.ru/invoices/invoice/14/1
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36
> Expires: -1
> Content-Length: 193
> 
* upload completely sent off: 193 out of 193 bytes
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< date: Thu, 31 Dec 2020 13:51:06 GMT
date: Thu, 31 Dec 2020 13:51:06 GMT
< content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
< server: envoy
server: envoy
< cache-control: no-store, no-cache, max-age=0
cache-control: no-store, no-cache, max-age=0
< pragma: no-cache
pragma: no-cache
< x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 434
x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 434
< transfer-encoding: chunked
transfer-encoding: chunked

< 
{"id_token":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IkNCMTUyQ0U0RTk0MTgxQzVFNDREN0IxNzYzRkY5ODJBIiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0.eyJuYmYiOjE2MDk0MjI2NjYsImV4cCI6MTYwOTQyMjk2NiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9mYW5jcnlwdG8ucnUiLCJhdWQiOiJicm93c2VyIiwiaWF0IjoxNjA5NDIyNjY2LCJhdF9oYXNoIjoid0JPM2FBblFmTWpCd3U2UVpFQ0twUSIsInN1YiI6IjE4ZjBkMDk1LWNmY2QtNDY1ZC04NGNkLTU4YmM3OTg0NDFjMiIsImF1dGhfdGltZSI6MTYwOTQwNjUwOCwiaWRwIjoibG9jYWwiLCJnaXZlbl9uYW1lIjoiWmVmaXIwMiIsImFtciI6WyJwd2QiXX0.zfniYLBEzUKUetSZ__-vdUr71yXHDj3tadzZK2Q9EIwYrQlCXOzvo2X1PEslIhKtDCSybZQSckjbuiSinxT_B2pimbBOprIc1yCx6JK4WNW_tuvHDC4luzm_q2sZInXa_iimdcVOTo-phbFnWV7zuiQ4d_SMQUmhm2CfKyMv_jhEawMfbq5GG2OjtE-BoXNMu1U90voHczs1nCAQtnCP8ofpk2pKX0TntWVFZHb6uP9lF4l8-xEpUjdxIuXMEXn6Swh2gKuE3ZUV3rqwNczGQQ5A24yXhYRGhUEEAR8fe4OJNgh5FsHtpF6bxvjNLF2aryb3qQq7T31iOJL-Sn80tA","access_token":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IkNCMTUyQ0U0RTk0MTgxQzVFNDREN0IxNzYzRkY5ODJBIiwidHlwIjoiYXQrand0In0.eyJuYmYiOjE2MDk0MjI2NjYsImV4cCI6MTYwOTQyMjc0MSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9mYW5jcnlwdG8ucnUiLCJhdWQiOiJhcGkxIiwiY2xpZW50X2lkIjoiYnJvd3N* Connection #0 to host fancrypto.ru left intact
lciIsInN1YiI6IjE4ZjBkMDk1LWNmY2QtNDY1ZC04NGNkLTU4YmM3OTg0NDFjMiIsImF1dGhfdGltZSI6MTYwOTQwNjUwOCwiaWRwIjoibG9jYWwiLCJnaXZlbl9uYW1lIjoiWmVmaXIwMiIsImp0aSI6IjREQjU4QkYxOTZERUI3OUE4QkI5MzVDRjgxMjAzQTk3IiwiaWF0IjoxNjA5NDA2NTA4LCJzY29wZSI6WyJvcGVuaWQiLCJwcm9maWxlX3NlY3VyaXR5IiwidHJhZGUiLCJvZmZsaW5lX2FjY2VzcyJdLCJhbXIiOlsicHdkIl19.s-HQ3Cb2ZG1GKbfqlrWZMED7TvWUvU7jX0q7yNAa6E2i4G39TXRE7k_qmYcQ4zg0LZXYsPgBjaWi0BBs_7AikB-LpAz5kPEYeuMT7vBX8tQw12aJ9ZG5_-IXdikRTrbsu-SaIeydyHPsVsRtti5tbhXzJzGOAwEXzTrUN-df0yyk7DV_pEt0mqzN4POcsE5-rwSaYnL4QPkxDfs96KdH5AddJ327zG3wccKOXDNZ1whC398MgF9EP63fBzLKsajD2ncSGJw4k85wf8n1Chiy129SzsOAc67xfymZUjU3DnN8RCy624Kc_KM9TqES8MuaQPJT4jAVedWUlarp6JlZew","expires_in":75,"token_type":"Bearer","refresh_token":"FA84B084C5D037A949167A60CB0BF5D418A146DB2923040C371D5DFD722E173B","scope":"openid profile_security trade offline_access"}
```

Comment: То есть сервер получает запрос?

Comment: нет. запрос вообще не выходит из браузера. таймаутится через 5сек прямо в браузере.

Comment: "Смотрел в нгинксе, они туда даже попадают" А это что значит?

Comment: т.е. в логах обратного прокси чисто. не приходят запросы после открытия третьей вкладки.